# Laravel Valet installation

Tags: php, laravel

In trying to get Laravel Valet up and running, I have stumbled upon this issue. When running 'valet install' or 'valet park' or any valet-command at all, I get the following error:

```
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare info() (previously declared in /Users/jantore/.composer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:454) in /Users/jantore/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/includes/helpers.php on line 20
> 
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare info() (previously declared in
> /Users/jantore/.composer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:454)
> in
> /Users/jantore/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/includes/helpers.php
> on line 20 eger:~ jantore$
```

I went through the helpers.php document and tried to comment out the info()-function, but that didn't make a difference.

I have a fresh Brew install with PHP 7.0 as per the Valet-install instructions.

Anyone have any clue what this might be?

---

Update: As per Ben Swinbourne's suggestion I tried with `composer global dump-autoload`. Unfortunately the same result, no change in the error. Thanx to Ben for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Try `composer global dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, I recently had a similar issue, except mine was around the retry() function.

to solve it.

```
composer global remove laravel/valet
composer global require laravel/valet
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help you, try deleting the **composer.lock** file and the **vendor** directory and then do a `composer update`.

Comment: Nope, no change, thanx though

Comment: have you trying starting over?

Comment: Yep, same issue, both on both my Macs. I guess I'll try again though, but so strange the issue is present on both machines.